# How do I get Activity Context in FloatWindow with Button OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-context

I have a FloatWindow,it has a static method with `view.Button OnClickListener`,
I want Show Dialog in any Activity When I Click the View,But the Context can't not used the `getApplicationContext`, it will Show `"Unable to add window token null is not for an application"`, So How do I get the Activity context when I Click the View?

```
//the Para is getapplicationcontext,but is not work 

public static void createStatusWindow(Context context) {

        WindowManager windowManager = getWindowManager(context);
        int screenWidth = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        int screenHeight = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

        if (statusWindow == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            statusWindow = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.floatwindow, null);
            statusWindow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
       MessageBox.show("GPS Status", "Good", MessageBox.Icon.Alert,context,true);
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
   }
```

Comment: make it final. `createStatusWindow(final Context context)`

Comment: Sorry I did not make it clear,my createStatusWindow() is in a Service,When the App is First Open,it will work,So,In Service can I get the Activity?

Comment: Service is also a Context.

Answer (score 0):

try using `yourActivityName.this` 
in place of `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: But I want show dialog in any Activity,So the Activity Name can't fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can make a reference from your activity and then pass it to your `createStatusWindow` method:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity{

private YourActivity mContext;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = this;
        createStatusWindow(mContext);

}
```

Now change the `context` variable in your `createStatusWindow` method to final as follows:

```
public static void createStatusWindow(final Context context) {

        WindowManager windowManager = getWindowManager(context);
        int screenWidth = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        int screenHeight = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

        if (statusWindow == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            statusWindow = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.floatwindow, null);
            statusWindow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
       MessageBox.show("GPS Status", "Good", MessageBox.Icon.Alert,context,true);
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
   }
```

It will work.

Comment: Sorry I did not make it clear,my  createStatusWindow() is in a Service,When the App is First Open,it will work,So,In Service can I get the Activity?

Comment: You can pass a reference from your activity to the Service and assign it to a Context